# Tag merge request: [webstart] and [java-web-start]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

There are two Java Web Start tags:

[webstart](/questions/tagged/webstart): **x 239**
[java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start): **x 320**

- Both tags refer to the same technology
- [webstart's wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/webstart/info) refers to [java-web-start's wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info)
- both wiki point to [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136112.html)
- all questions tagged with [webstart](/questions/tagged/webstart) clearly relate to Java Web Start

I suggest they be merged into [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start) (which appears in the auto-complete list if one types "webstart" in the Tags box when asking a new question).

Comment: [java-web-start] is already a suggested synonym for [jnlp].  That's preventing me from making the [webstart] --> [java-web-start] suggestion.  Good Lord, I'm swimming in synonyms.

Comment: @RobertHarvey IMHO, jnlp refers to a specific file format used by java web start but java web start is a lot more than jnlp. I think both tags are valid: java web start for questions about the deployment technology, jnlp for questions about the format/content of the file used for the deployment.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Side note: it would be great to be able to let the top answerers know about such tag merge / synonyms requests as they are probably the best placed to make an informed decision.

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192204/

Answer (score 3):

I deleted the suggested [jnlp](/questions/tagged/jnlp) ← [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start) synonym. At minimum, if the two really are that related, that synonym should be reversed.

I also added the requested [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start) ← [webstart](/questions/tagged/webstart) synonym and approved the suggested [javaws](/questions/tagged/javaws) synonym. Should be all good to go now.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm offering you a bounty just for that!

Comment: Hallelujah! Thanks @gparyani for insisting.