# Can't propose tag synonym (already proposed)

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

A while ago [I proposed to merge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137926/tag-merge-request-webstart-and-java-web-start) [webstart](/questions/tagged/webstart) with [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start). They are indeed exactly the same thing.

However, somebody has also proposed to make [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start) a synonym of [jnlp](/questions/tagged/jnlp):

- not only is this proposal disputable: web start is the deployment mechanism whereas jnlp is an xml file that holds the configuration required for the deployment - so even though the 2 concepts are closely related, they can't really be called synonyms
- but it also prevents anybody to suggest the webstart/java-web-start synonym: "synonym java-web-start already proposed on the tag jnlp"

The situation could go on forever (it has already been a few months). Is there anything that could be done about this?

Comment: I don't see why [tag:java-web-start] should be a synonym of [tag:jnlp]. (IMO, it should be the other way around.) If only whoever who proposed it could retract it, we could finally merge [tag:java-web-start] and [tag:webstart]. I don't understand why no one got back to this discussion, as I was about to post the same, but stopped in hopes of not having my question marked as duplicate of this.