# Make [webstart] a synonym of [java-web-start]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

First off, I know that this question could be considered a duplicate of [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137926/), but see what I'm about to tell you. I know that [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start) has already been proposed as a synonym for [jnlp](/questions/tagged/jnlp), which it shouldn't be, because JNLP, or Java Network Launch Protocol, is the 
protocol used BY Java Web Start to operate. Now, these questions have been largely unnoticed, with the moderators simply commenting that they can't, because of the synonym problem. In my opinion, the moderator should have:

1. looked at the definitions of [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start) and [jnlp](/questions/tagged/jnlp) and
   seen that the synonym proposal was incorrect,
2. rejected the proposal to make it so that other tags can be synonyms
   of [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start), and
3. proposed [webstart](/questions/tagged/webstart) to be a synonym of [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start)

However, none of these actions were taken, and I feel that moderators seem to be simply not doing anything about them (by that, I mean not even marking it as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)). For now, I just post my JWS questions under both tags. Why didn't the moderator do anything in the last question?

Comment: I guess someone is trying to make a joke, by casting a dupe close-vote to the question you linked to.  Good luck.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that should be posted as an **answer** to that question: *"I think this is a good idea; I don't know why this has been ignored by the moderators thus far. I think you should blah blah blah, because blah blah blah."*

Comment: @Downvoter Why the downvote?